# Pandas: regex search function skipping matches and returning incorrect results

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to extract alpha numeric code from various fields in data. The code could be in any of three fields. I need the first match -- then extract the code with a substitution/capture group to populate the "code" column.

In the toy example below, the output is what I would expect ( AKA: it "works" ). In my production version, it skips obvious matches ( not all, small number ) and on another small number, the substitution results in smushed results or a full return of the matched field.

Toy data:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1000, 'File X234 version 2.pdf', 'My Title 8209','BR1',''], 
                    [1001, 'File_X003.pdf', 'Title X003', 'BR1',''], 
                    [1003, 'File.pdf', 'BR3 8200', 'BR2',''],
                    [1004, 'BR5_file.doc','BR4 F200','BR1',''],
                    [1005, 'file.txt', 'Title', 'BR1', ''],
                    [1006, '8208 doc3.txt', 'doc3', 'BR4', '']],
                   columns=['ID', 'File Name', 'Title', 'Type','Code'])
```

REGEX paterns with capture groups:

```
patternA   = re.compile(r'^.*(82[0-9]{2}).*$', re.IGNORECASE)
patternB   = re.compile(r'^.*(X[0-9]{3}).*$', re.IGNORECASE)
patternC   = re.compile(r'^.*(F[0-9]{3}).*$', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Function very similar to production version:

```
def func_bar(x):
    text = x['File Name'] + x['Title']

    if patternA.search(text): 
        value = patternA.sub(r"\1", text)
        return value
    elif patternB.search(text): 
        value = patternB.sub(r'\1', text)
        return value
    elif patternC.search(text): 
        value = patternC.sub(r'\1', text)
        return value
    else: return "Not Found"
```

Apply function to column:

```
df3['Code'] = df3.apply(func_bar, axis=1)
```

Success(?):

```
    ID          File Name                   Title           Type    Code
0   1000        File X234 version 2.pdf     My Title 8209   BR1     8209
1   1001        File_X003.pdf               Title X003      BR1     X003
2   1003        File.pdf                    BR3 8200        BR2     8200
3   1004        BR5_file.doc                BR4 F200        BR1     F200
4   1005        file.txt                    Title           BR1     Not Found
5   1006        8208 doc3.txt               doc3            BR4     8208
```

Any ideas why my production version is:

- skipping just a few obvious matches?
- Smushing output ( only a few )
- Returning the whole matched field?

Comment: Maybe you just need `df3['Title'].str.extract(r'((?:82|[XF]\d)\d{2})').fillna("Not found")`? You do not have any useful information in the `File Name` column.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in the production data, there are 3 fields that potentially contain the code. It could be in any one of them and not in the other 2. It's not consistent or predictable. I will try and make the toy data more realistic. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so, you might just use `df3['code'] = df3['File Name'] + df3['Title']` (or `+` more cols) and then `df3['code'] = df3['code'].str.extract(r'((?:82|[XF]\d)\d{2})').fillna("Not found")`, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In cases where the codes might have highly variable patterns, it seems like a function would be more readable. Are functions possible in this scenario?

Comment: Use extract here, it will be more efficient.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what about a situation where matches need to be ordered in terms of priority? Ie., this match first, this match if and only if the first failed. Each successive match is just a failover for the preceding?

Comment: I just answered the question you asked. If you have a different question (and you already asked a ton), please ask a new question. However, you know how to use `apply` and write your own  functions, I do not see a problem for you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the necessary columns into a `code` column, and then extract with a single regex:

```py
df3['code'] = df3['File Name'] + df3['Title'] # add more columns if needed
df3['code'] = df3['code'].str.extract(r'((?:82|[XF]\d)\d{2})').fillna("Not found")
```

Output:

```
")
>>> df3
     ID                File Name          Title Type Code       code
0  1000  File X234 version 2.pdf  My Title 8209  BR1            X234
1  1001            File_X003.pdf     Title X003  BR1            X003
2  1003                 File.pdf       BR3 8200  BR2            8200
3  1004             BR5_file.doc       BR4 F200  BR1            F200
4  1005                 file.txt          Title  BR1       Not found
5  1006            8208 doc3.txt           doc3  BR4            8208
```

The `((?:82|[XF]\d)\d{2})` regex matches

- `(?:82|[XF]\d)` - `82`, or `X` or `F` and a digit
- `\d{2}` - two digits.

The `Series.str.extract` returns the first match found.

If you want to use several regexps just OR them with the `|` alternation operator:

```py
regexps = [r'82[0-9]{2}', r'X[0-9]{3}', r'F[0-9]{3}'] # etc.
df3['code'] = df3['File Name'] + df3['Title'] # add more columns if needed
df3['code'].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(regexps)})").fillna("Not found")
```

**Solution with a separate function**

When it is impossible to merge your regular expressions into a single one, you can use the following approach (note I added a regex to extract a non-empty string between the first pair of double quotes):

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1000, 'File X234 version 2.pdf', 'My Title 8209','BR1',''], 
                    [1001, 'File_X003.pdf', 'Title X003', 'BR1',''], 
                    [1003, 'File.pdf', 'BR3 8200', 'BR2',''],
                    [1004, 'BR5_file.doc','BR4 F200','BR1',''],
                    [1005, 'file.txt', 'Title', 'BR1', ''],
                    [1006, '8208 doc3.txt', 'doc3', 'BR4', ''],
                    [1006, '"some valuable stuff here" doc3.txt', 'doc3', 'BR4', '']],
                   columns=['ID', 'File Name', 'Title', 'Type','Code'])

def func_bar(x):
    text = x['File Name'] + x['Title']
    rx1 = re.compile(r'(?:82|[XF]\d)\d{2}')
    rx2 = re.compile(r'"([^"]+)"')
    m1 = rx1.search(text)
    if m1:
        return m1.group()
    m2 = rx2.search(text)
    if m2:
        return m2.group(1)
    return "Not found"
```

Output:

```
>>> df3.apply(func_bar, axis=1)
0                        X234
1                        X003
2                        8200
3                        F200
4                   Not found
5                        8208
6    some valuable stuff here
```

Comment: What about a case where codes could be different lengths ....etc. Seems like at some point a function would be easier to read.

Comment: @EABubnoff If you use `re.X` / `(?x)`, any pattern will be easy to read.

Comment: I should avoid functions, I take it? If I have 10 possible permutations ...etc., there is no version in which a function might be permissible?

Comment: @EABubnoff `.apply` will make the code much slower. If you show me your 10 regexps, I will probably be able to make a single pattern out of them.

Comment: It seems though, that at some point, readability and repeatability gain in priority as complexity goes up. Same point with Linux one-liners or concise fast code versus maintainability. Are functions in Pandas always bad practice?

Comment: @EABubnoff Here, it is. Even from the regex point of view, `.*` in the pattern used at the start will cause too much redundant backtracking. You might replace it with the lazy `.*?`, but this is not good if the match is at the end, or there is no match. Do not use `re.sub` to extract, it is regex bad practice. I added another "dynamic" way to build a single regex out of your patterns to be used with `str.extract`.

Comment: Here's an edge case for you. What about anything after the phrase "Invoice No." and bordered by spaces? In addition to the patterns in the regexp list. Ex. "Invoice No. X53-80003". The extraction should produce X53-80003. The tricky part is that there is no discernable pattern among the code occurring after this phrase other than the spaces at the "word boundaries".

Comment: @EABubnoff This is not a problem, `(?<=Invoice No\. )\S+`.

Comment: Won't that pull everything to the end of the sentence?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. `r'(?<=Invoice No\. )\S+(?= .*$)` 

Would that extract non-space chars between the lookahead and the lookbehind?

Comment: @EABubnoff Yes, and you do not need `.*$` in the lookahead. You only need `(?= )` if you *require* the space on the right (i.e. no match at the end of string).